# expected value and negative binomial distribution

Tags: probability

**Repeatedly roll a fair die until the outcome 3 has occurred on the 4th roll. Let
X be the number of times needed in order to achieve this goal. Find E(X).**

My Attempt :

Pr(getting a 3 on the 4th roll) : (5/6)^3 * (1/6)=.096

E(X)= 1/.096 = 10.36

The correct answer is supposed to be 24. Could someone please help me with where I'm wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer comes from a reasonable interpretation of a poorly phrased problem.

We give an interpretation, perhaps the intended one, that gives an answer of $24$.

We roll a die $4$ times. We call the sequence of rolls a **success** if the fourth roll gives a $3$. We do not care about whether we get one of more $3$'s before the $4$-th roll. If on a sequence of $4$ rolls we do not get a success, we repeat the process.

Let $X$ be the **total** number of dice rolls until we get a success. We want $E(X)$. In every sequence of $4$ rolls, the first three are irrelevant. So $X=4Y$ where $Y$ is a geometric random variable with parameter $\frac{1}{6}$. It follows that $E(X)=4E(Y)=(4)(6)$.